# find date interval for unique id excel

Tags: excel, for-loop, excel-formula, intervals

I am working with this data in excel. here is the original data

**input**

```
person1     2007
person1     2008
person1     2008
person1     2011
person2     2005
person2     2008
person2     2009
person3     2011
person3     2012
person3     2012
person3     2014
person4     2015
```

**whished ouput**

```
person1     2007    0
person1     2008    1   
person1     2008    0
person1     2011    3

person2     2005    0
person2     2008    3
person2     2009    1

person3     2011    0
person3     2012    1
person3     2012    0
person3     2014    2
person4     2015    0
```

I would like to use an excel function to find the year interval for the each person.
I have shown my input file and output file.
I can't think of anything right now, any ideas?

many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tell us what you want and **how** you want to generate the ouput. eggplant_parm's suggestion seems to generate what you asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an array formula that will display the MIN-MAX of each person:

```
{=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$13=A2,$B$2:$B$13,9999))&"-"& MAX(IF($A$2:$A$13=A2,$B$2:$B$13,1900))}
```

Need to validate with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[EDIT] Maybe I was thinking something too hard.

Is that what you want?

```
=B2-B1
```

displays the difference between the year of the current row and the previous one - but that's too easy, I must have missed something.

[EDIT 2] Credits to eggplant_parm (cf. comments) - I forgot to reset for each person

```
=if(a2=a1,b2-b1,0)
```

Comment: hmm, B2-B1 can only work for I have few users, however I have like 10k records. Also the difference is only true for that particular user id.

Comment: You can drag and drop the formula till the end of your range (double-click on the bottom-right corner of the cell containing the formula will do the trick). Please explain more your questions so that we could help.

Comment: This will reset to 0 with each new user. =if(a2=a1,b2-b1,0)